# Литература по PHP на русском

Tags: php, книги

Здравствуйте!
Для изучения PHP мне выслали список рекомендуемой литературы на английском:

- Sams: PHP And MySQL Web Development;
- Jesus Castagnetto, Harish Rawat, Sascha Schumann, Chris Scollo, Deepak Veliath: Professional PHP Programming (Wrox edition);
- Leon Atkinson, Zeev Suraski: Core PHP Programming (Third edition);
- PHP|Architect’s Guide to PHP Design Patterns, Jason E. Sweat, ISBN: 0973589825

Кто знает, где есть перевод этих книг на русском?

Comment: А я вот что-то не припомню, чтобы книги читал. Ну так, на 30 странице забил и стал исходники смотреть, экспериментировать. Самое главное - это понять принцип выполнения кода. Всё остальное можно найти в справочнике.

Comment: @lampa, вы не читали, но это не показатель. Не *всё остальное* можно найти в справочнике.

Comment: Методикам проектирования и  написания грамотного кода в справочниках не научишься. Чтобы не превратиться в быдлокодера и стать профессионалом, необходимо учиться, в том числе и по книгам. А PHP как раз печально  известен большим наличием быдлокодеров - очень уж либеральный язык. так что одними исходниками не обойтись (особенно учитывая, что у них может быть очень низкое качество)

Comment: @lampa, считаете равнозначным чтение книги, в которой автор в выверенном порядке преподносит то, чего достиг в результате своих поисков и поиск в интернете от фонаря? Попробуйте найти то, о чём не догадываетесь.

Comment: @DreamChild методика проектирования возникает в процессе написания проекта. Дальше это перерастает в опыт. Прочитать книгу это далеко не означает, что вы научитесь определенной методике. А то, что если вы разберетесь, причем сами, без чьей либо помощи, то это колоссальный опыт, который не получить, читая книгу.

Comment: lampa, вы считаете, что человек, который не имеет ни малейшего представления о таких вещах, как рефакторинг, паттерны проектирования и тому подобные вещи, не желающий читать литературы грамотных специалистов и мастеров своего дела, способен сам на собственном опыте достичь того, до чего методика разработки ПО шла несколько десятков лет? Теоретически - может, на практике - 99.99% таких "программистов" будут свято верить, что выучив if-else и for они уже умеют программировать. А опыт от такого "самодельного" обучения даже хуже, чем его отсутствие, потому что это опыт "как не надо делать".

Comment: А что такого сложного в словах "рефакторинг" и "паттерны"? Или они просто так круто звучат, что их сложно понять? И зачем читать мегатонны "букав", когда в справочнике написано про паттерны: это работает так, это так, другое так. Что я делаю дальше? Дальше я начинаю экспериментировать, пробовать, учиться. И как вы можете судить о собственном опыте, а не книжном, даже не зная на собственной шкуре, что это такое? А теоретически такие люди более грамотны, более подкованы, более сообразительны, ведь пока за вас думала книжка, они обучались сами. А это самое ценное.

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что я призываю только читать книги и не писать кода? Не стоит искать в моих словах того смысла, которого там нет. Код нужно писать всегда, в том числе и вместе со чтением литературы.  
 "теоретически такие люди более грамотны (...) ведь пока за вас думала книжка, они обучались сами" - я не знаю, как  конкретно Вы читаете книги, но вообще книги надо не просто читать, чтобы "за вас думала книга", а думать вместе с ней и даже больше (к чему, кстати, хорошие авторы всегда подталкивают) А что касается тех же паттернов, то вы видимо даже не знаете что это такое , раз так говорите)

Comment: @DreamChild во всех случаях по-любому книга будет думать за вас, подсказывать вам. Вы для этого и читаете её, чтобы набраться этих "подсказок" и использовать их. И да, не любая книга будет правильна также, как и любой исходник. И, о да, гуру, вы сами то, видимо, только что узнали про шаблоны и теперь выпендриваетесь :-) Удачи в начинаниях.

Comment: еще раз хотел бы попросить не искать в моих словах того чего я не говорил - я же нигде себя не называл гуру)) Раз уж на то пошло, то гуру у нас Вы - учиться у умных людей вы не желаете, стало быть, полагаете, что знаете никак не меньше их (это я ни в коем случае не о себе, а об авторах той литературы, о важности/неважности которой мы с Вами спорим)
  Если вы считаете, что "во всех случаях по-любому книга будет думать за вас" - я искренне Вам сочувствую, если вы, читая книгу,  не способны мыслить самостоятельно, вне рамок книги. Многие людей все же способны справиться с этой тривиальной задаче

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что нашёл:

Leon Atkinson, Zeev Suraski: Core PHP Programming
В переводе: [PHP 5. Библиотека профессионала](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2224132/)

Но английский всё равно знать надо, хотя бы на уровне чтения.
Если же совсем никак, то просите список уже переведенных книг.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, с английским у меня туговато:( Учу потихоньку, пытаюсь manual на php.net читать.